# "facebook.com" missing from login page URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I can not login with facebook from any applications, including from mine. This is caused by the lack of "facebook.com" in login page URL. When we click the login button, the URL should be

> https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=XXX....

but in my case :

> https://www./login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=XXX.. (without "facebook.com")

So, the web page can not display anything. It just happened today, everything was normal yesterday. I have try facebook basic example code and the problem still same. Here's the code :

```
<?php

require 'facebook.php';


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '137737616434442',
  'secret' => 'XXX',
  'baseurl' => 'http://localhost/facebookconnect/login/example.php',
));


$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}


if ($user) {

  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array( 'next' => 'http://localhost/facebookconnect/login/example.php' ));
  session_destroy();  
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'scope' => 'email,user_birthday,friends_birthday,publish_stream,user_location,friends_location,user_work_history,user_likes,friends_work_history,user_about_me,friends_about_me,user_hometown',
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/facebookconnect/login/example.php'));

}


$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Can you post some example code please? Feel free to edit out your application ID, however we will need some code to look at.

Comment: My app encounter the same problem. missing "facebook.com" after called FB.Login()

Comment: @AndrewWhite edited.. I think the problem is not from the facebook app, because of this problem applies to all web app, including stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restart my connection and, everything is back to normal. Looks weird, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's Facebook app problem. Looks like the problem occurs everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

My Facebook page is missing today (August 28, 2013) too!  It was there at midnight last night but won't load today!  My Outlook/Hotmail won't work either.  Loads but won't open anything.  I think it's been hijacked after a friend's hotmail was hijacked.  This computer is going to the hospital tomorrow.  Until then it is being unplugged from the internet.